# Android 7.1 certificates are going to expire, anyway to renew them?

Tags: certificates

starting from September android 7.1 and below users are going to have issues with the internet
so is there anyway to renew those certificates so i can use my phone properly?

Comment: Kind of related: [Let's Encrypt: Is there a workaround for the 2021 SSL “cutoff” for pre-7.1.1 Android devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231025/44325)

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific about what certificates you are talking about?