# Android 7 breaks certificates on Samsung Browser and in Whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, 7.0-nougat, certificates, https, samsung-internet-browser

On a Samsung S6 Plus Edge running on Android 7, certain security certificates will break since September 2021: [the workaround](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/12/21/the-internet-wont-break-on-older-android-devices-in-2021-thanks-to-certificate-authoritys-workaround/) which Let's Encrypt implemented doesn't seem to work in Samsung Internet. I get the standard "Back to safety" screen.

For browsing this is not an issue, I can use firefox. But I have an issue with WhatsApp: it will not load preview images from such websites, as probably it routes such requests through Samsung Internet or some samsung API. Changing the default browser doesn't help.

Is there a workaround for this which doesn't involve rooting the device ?
I've seen [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232051/364397), but it looks like I can't install certificates manually if the device isn't rooted.

Comment: `doesn't seem to work in Samsung Internet` - it is more "does not work in any app except Firefox as Firefox has it's own certificate trust store". As your device does not receives updates the only alternatives are rooting + installing the Let's Encrypt certificate or install a custom ROM with a newer Android version.

Comment: @Robert "Both owners of older Android devices and Let's Encrypt subscribers shouldn't need to do anything for this workaround to function" according to [the article on androidpolice I've linked](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/12/21/the-internet-wont-break-on-older-android-devices-in-2021-thanks-to-certificate-authoritys-workaround/) ... And [according to Let's Encrypt](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/production-chain-changes/150739) "Android devices as far back as 2.3.6 will continue to work" until 2024. That's why I imagine Samsung as the culprit ...

Comment: `Samsung as the culprit` I agree with you, that is the most likely reason, too many modifications by Samsung but the relevant they missed or did something wrong.