# Android emulator not connecting behind proxy even configurated for it

Tags: proxy, android-studio

I've a android emulator, that is running on a computer that is behind a proxy.

From computer perspective, http and https internet access works fine, but on Android Emulator, nothing.

So I tried with "Use Android Studio HTTP proxy settings" and nothing, so I setup a "Manual proxy configuration", and it was accepted:

[image]

Doing this, I turned this virtual machine, off, and on, but still there is no internet:

[image]

Anyone here knows what is missing, and what do I need to do more?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE1:

I've setup also on WIFI settings, and seems to be setup, but still there is no internet:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure HTTP and HTTPS don't work in the emulator? If the proxy is an intercepting proxy with HTTPS decryption and the certificate is added as trusted on your Windows system HTTPS will fail as Android doesn't trust the certificate but HTTP may work (test with `http://neverssl.com`).

Comment: With http://neverssl.com, or any http or https url, the result is always the same after doing that UPDATE 1: Contacting the system admin (Who is me) ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Comment: Is the proxy an HTTPS url? If yes make install the used rot CA certificate is also installed in the emulator (not sure if this is sufficient). If not you need a rooted emulator and install the CA certificate as system root CA. See [second half of this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232051/2241) on an example how to install a system root CA certificate.

Comment: The DHCP is setup on WIFI, and its getting a range of IPs, that are not the same of this machine, so I think that is being given by android studio emulator NAT, is that it? (cannot find any config related to this VM network, outside of the VM it self)

Comment: the proxy url is a http url

Comment: Then I don't know. Use Wireshark to capture the traffic from emulator to your proxy to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host is placed in a network that has a proxy auto config.

For this case the recepie that worked for me was leaving "Use Android Studio HTTP proxy settings" check, and only config WIFI to use to use auto Proxty config with full path for the pac file like this (in my case was a http with an https it could be needed a certificate):

http://proxyautoconfig.domain.com/proxy.pac