# How to enable lock screen password in BlueStacks 5 on Android 7.0 Nougat?

Tags: root-access, lock-screens, 7.0-nougat, password, bluestacks

I installed Bluestacks 5 recently. It is also rooted. I want to install a CA certificate on the device which is Android 7.0. To install the certificate, I have to set the screen lock first. But when I check the Settings, I can't find any lock screen password.

I did manage to access the password setting somehow but it automatically set to None. So I am not able to set any password in it.

Please help me to set a password.

Comment: If you have root access it should be easier to install the root CA certificate by modifying the system. The second part of [my answer about installing the Let's encrypt CA certificates](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232051/2241) should show you how to do so.