# Block URLs from Android Webview

Tags: security, firewall, aosp, webview, url

I am looking for a solution to block all URLs except a few which are required for my device to function. I have all the root permissions required to make changes.

Is there any way we can block all URLs except a list of URLs (approx. 10 URLs) from a common place in android Web-view Framework so that all the Native applications can access the common code and access set of Allowed and Blocked URLs

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245445/2241

Comment: Run [dnscrypt-proxy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/207647/218526) on your device which allows very flexible whitelisting / blacklisting of domains.