# Why don't Google services work on Android 4 versions?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google

For some reason, in recent days I can’t go into either maps or mail from my old tablet, I write there is no connection. Although other applications work fine, the Internet does not complain. Google disabled 4ver. support? I would be grateful if you check for yourself.

**ADB LOG**

```
E/CheckinTask(  582): SSL error, attempting time correction: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1158a28: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer

E/CheckinTask(  582): Checkin failed: https://android.clients.google.com/checkin (request #0): javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x1158a28: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: With the release of Android version 10, Google has stopped support for Android 7 or earlier https://endoflife.date/android

Comment: @alecxs That is support of Android OS itself (no changes to AOSP) but not for Google services. E.g. login to Google on devices with less than Android 3 was ended July 2021. And Play services updates for Android 4.1-4.3 were ended in August 2021.

Comment: Would updating the certificate help? In Google services, certificates are not built into the apk?

Comment: I don't think it is related but as you asked about... https://android.stackexchange.com/q/231025